# Evaluating limit with Taylor

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

I need to solve the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to\sqrt3}\frac{\pi-3\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\pi-3\arctan (x)}
$$
then with $t=x-\sqrt3$ we have for $x\to\sqrt3$ that $t\to0$, so i tried
$$\arcsin{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt3}{2}\right)}=\left(\frac{t+\sqrt3}{2}\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt3}{2}\right)^3}{6}+o(t^3)=\left(\frac{t+\sqrt3}{2}\right)+\frac{\left({t+\sqrt3}\right)^3}{48}+o(t^3)$$
and
$$
\arctan{\left(t+\sqrt3\right)}=\left(t+\sqrt3\right)-\frac{\left(t+\sqrt3\right)^3}{3}+o(t^3)
$$
which eventually gets me to a polynomial of grade 3 and by dividing the coefficients i get $-\frac1{16}$, which is not the correct solution.

Is the problem with the Taylor expansions or have I made some other error in between?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You are expanding around $0$ instead of $\sqrt 3$. Use $f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+o((x-x_0)^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Taylor formula for $x \mapsto \arctan(x)$, at the order $1$ and the point $a=\sqrt{3}$, one has
$$\arctan(x)=\arctan(\sqrt{3}) + \arctan'(\sqrt{3})\left(x-\sqrt{3} \right) + \mathop{o}\limits_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{3}}\left(x-\sqrt{3} \right) $$

i.e.
$$\arctan(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{3} + \dfrac{1}{4}\left(x-\sqrt{3}\right) + \mathop{o}\limits_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{3}}\left(x-\sqrt{3} \right)$$

which rewrites as
$$\boxed{\pi-3\arctan(x)=\dfrac{3}{4}\left(\sqrt{3}-x\right) + \mathop{o}\limits_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{3}}\left(x-\sqrt{3} \right)}$$

Similarly, Taylor formula for $f : x \mapsto \arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$, at the order $1$ and the point $a=\sqrt{3}$ gives
$$\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)=\arcsin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) + f'(\sqrt{3})\left(x-\sqrt{3}\right) + \mathop{o}\limits_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{3}}\left(x-\sqrt{3} \right)$$

i.e.
$$\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{3} + x-\sqrt{3} + \mathop{o}\limits_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{3}}\left(x-\sqrt{3} \right)$$

which rewrites as
$$\boxed{\pi-3\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)=3(\sqrt{3}-x) + \mathop{o}\limits_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{3}}\left(x-\sqrt{3} \right)}$$

Finally, one gets
$$\dfrac{\pi-3\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{\pi-3\arctan(x)} \mathop{\sim}\limits_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{3}}  \frac{3(\sqrt{3}-x)}{\frac{3}{4}(\sqrt{3}-x)} = 4 $$

so finally,
$$\boxed{\lim_{x \rightarrow \sqrt{3}} \dfrac{\pi-3\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{\pi-3\arctan(x)}  = 4}$$